# Why does this SqlCommand parameter produce SQLDateTime overflow error?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have these blocks of code:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand (); 
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " Where ";
SqlConnection a = new SqlConnection("the setting");
cmd.Connection = a;
```

These lines below work fine:

```
cmd.CommandText += strFromTextBox + " LIKE '%" + strUserInput + "%'";
//strFromTextBox & strUserInput is string datatype
//it looks like 'apple', 'ladder', just normal string
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

But these ones produced error:

```
DateTime dtFrom = DateTime.Parse(dt1).Date;
DateTime dtTo = DateTime.Parse(dt2).Date;
//dt1 & dt2 is originally a string
//they look something like this: 2/1/2012 12:00:00 AM
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt1", @dtFrom); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt2", @dtTo);
cmd.CommandText+= parameter[i].ToString() + " BETWEEN @dt1 AND @dt2";
//parameter[i] refers to the column name
```

The error it produced:

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow.

Both blocks are processed through:

```
DataTable Table = new DataTable();
adapter.FillSchema(Table, SchemaType.Source);
adapter.Fill(Table);
```

The final query output (found during character)

```
SELECT * FROM linkDb Where CreateDt BETWEEN @dt1 AND @dt2
```

Can someone advises whats wrong with those lines of code?

Comment: obviously not, pls do check the blocks of code i provide.. i put one commented line to show sample of the inputs..

Comment: I have done so. TQ. In fact I have other friend helping me to check the code too.. It's not from the input..

Comment: Can you tell me "parameter[i]" what is this?

Comment: It refers to column name, i have edited it.. thank you for spotting it..

Comment: @marc_s I edited my question, can't put here due to the ampersand character not allowed to typed more than 1 in comment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Server DATETIME datatype can only represent dates from 00:00:00 1/1/1753 to 23:59:59 31/12/9999. My guess is that one of the date strings is either being given a date outside this range, or it is being parsed differently than you think.

Also, building SQL strings like that is hugely prone to SQL injection. You should consider abandoning this practice very soon. Like, now.

Comment: I know. But please do check my question throughly I did provide example of the input... which is lying between the normal timeline.. //they look something like this: 2/1/2012 12:00:00 AM the error looks contrasting with my input that's why...

Comment: As marc_s already said: _check your assumptions_. Something I've learned is that when reality is clashing with your expectations, reality is usually correct.

Comment: Unless there is a bug in SQL server or .net base class library (which is highly impossible as being used by millions), error is in the input, date string is null or empty resulting in DateTime.MinValue which is outside SQL range.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt1", @dtFrom); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt2", @dtTo);
```

Try this:

```
SqlParameterCollection p = cmd.Parameters;
p.Add("@dt1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtFrom;
p.Add("@dt2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtTo;
```

I would also set the value of `CommandText` before setting the parameters.

If that fails as well, you should use a debugger to verify the values contained in `dtFrom` and `dtTo`.

BTW, I know it wasn't part of your question, but your posted code is susceptible to SQL injection. You should also wrap your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects with `using` statements.